# Postfix cleanup daemon access control

Tags: postfix

Is there any way to control which hosts are permitted to connect to the cleanup daemon over TCP?

Our 'master.cf' contains:

```
2526      inet  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
```

This is necessary because we have a cluster of SMTP servers running custom code, and they can all inject mail to the centralized postfix server via the cleanup daemon.

However, we want to allow *only* our authorized servers to connect to the cleanup daemon. The current configuration allows any host to connect to port 2526.

Clearly we can use iptables to restrict access, but is there a way to do this within postfix itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell the cleanup daemon does not have any auth controls. You could try to write a [non-smtp milter](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html#non-smtp-milters), but the functionality is pretty limited and I'm not sure it would even help.

The better option might be to expose [qmqpd](http://www.postfix.org/qmqpd.8.html) instead. It should pipe things directly into cleanup, but allows you to do simple controls. [qmqpd_authorized_clients](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#qmqpd_authorized_clients) would be the way to handle it there. I'd suspect you'd need to rewrite some code if you go this route.

Comment: Thanks. That was pretty much the conclusion I had come to as well. And welcome to Serverfault and the StackExchange network!

Comment: heh, no problem and always good to get a second pair of eyes.